# How to Style jQuery slick arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style the arrows for `.customer-logos` to look like http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/q1qznouw/664/. So far I have this https://jsfiddle.net/huten0wq/71/. The left arrow is larger than the right arrow, the "previous" and "next" still shows underneath, and I can't get the arrows to display slightly off to the sides of `.customer-logos` so that they're not over top the logos.

```
.customer-logos button {
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
z-index: 1;
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(1) {
left: 0;
background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1229/6958/files/arrow-  18_large.png?v=1486731677");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(3) {
right: 0;
background-image: url("//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1229/6958/files/arrow- 18_right_large.png?v=1486731840");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}


.customer-logos {
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
 .customer-logos button {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 1;
}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(1) {
left: 0;

}
.customer-logos button:nth-child(3) {
 right: 0;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows are of the same size, both are `20x33`. However, here are the tweaks you were looking for. Lines of importance are highlighted.

```
.customer-logos button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-indent: -99999px; /* getting rid of text */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* vertical centering */
}

.customer-logos {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 0 40px; /* padding on both sides, for arrows */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbj7ckrs/